# CSS floating problem : how can you position the boxes one below the other?

Tags: css, css-float

I'm trying out something here with floating the boxes in a container. The problem I'm having is that if the content gets too big in one of the containers the sub-container below it does not position itself right below it,instead it floats left from the edge of the top container. Hope I'm making some sense. I'm posting the code below, this might give a u better idea. And I'm also attaching the image for what I'm trying to achieve. If the question is not clear please let me know.

Thank You

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>containers</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<style>
#container{width:700px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;overflow:hidden;background:red;}
.subContainer{width:340px;background:blue;float:left;}
.subContainer:nth-child(even){background:green;float:right;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">
        <div class="subContainer">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas non lorem sem, et scelerisque augue. 
                Integer ut tortor libero, vel aliquam sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus 
                et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus id aliquet sapien. Cras sit amet diam sed massa bibendum fringilla. 
                Donec aliquet posuere urna. Vestibulum condimentum velit orci, ut iaculis tellus. Fusce sit amet ante felis. Nunc 
                quam felis, venenatis sed tincidunt quis, auctor a orci. Aliquam mauris leo, lacinia eu placerat vitae, placerat 
                sit amet sapien. Etiam eget dolor at neque dapibus pretium auctor non dui. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum rhoncus 
                urna id enim volutpat vehicula. Proin ut massa diam, quis condimentum sem. Nullam ac scelerisque neque. Donec tristique 
                tristique elit, nec vulputate turpis suscipit quis. Nam nisl purus, blandit non hendrerit eu, vestibulum vel justo. 
                Curabitur et massa sapien.Praesent laoreet, risus eu facilisis sodales, urna lectus condimentum felis, laoreet ullamcorper 
                sapien urna in lorem. Nulla ut sem sapien, ut aliquet augue. Curabitur nec lorem risus, in interdum augue. Sed aliquam sapien
                in sapien viverra iaculis mattis eros pulvinar. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse viverra purus vitae nibh lacinia
                at blandit arcu auctor. Mauris sapien lacus, euismod eget malesuada condimentum, bibendum a quam. Phasellus faucibus, orci in
                ultricies mollis, orci tortor sagittis eros, non iaculis lorem orci nec quam. Donec luctus bibendum risus et gravida. Sed at
                tortor vel metus elementum euismod. 
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="subContainer">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas non lorem sem, et scelerisque augue. 
                Integer ut tortor libero, vel aliquam sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
                et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus id aliquet sapien. Cras sit amet diam sed massa bibendum 
                fringilla. Donec aliquet posuere urna. Vestibulum condimentum velit orci, ut iaculis tellus. Fusce sit amet 
                ante felis. Nunc quam felis, venenatis sed tincidunt quis, auctor a orci. Aliquam mauris leo, lacinia eu 
                placerat vitae, placerat sit amet sapien. Etiam eget dolor at neque dapibus pretium auctor non dui. Aliquam 
                erat volutpat. Vestibulum rhoncus urna id enim volutpat vehicula. Proin ut massa diam, quis condimentum sem. 
                Nullam ac scelerisque neque. Donec tristique tristique elit, nec vulputate turpis suscipit quis. Nam nisl purus, 
                blandit non hendrerit eu, vestibulum vel justo. Curabitur et massa sapien. 
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="subContainer">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas non lorem sem, et scelerisque augue. 
                Integer ut tortor libero, vel aliquam sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus 
                et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus id aliquet sapien. Cras sit amet diam sed massa bibendum fringilla. 
                Donec aliquet posuere urna. Vestibulum condimentum velit orci, ut iaculis tellus. Fusce sit amet ante felis. Nunc 
                quam felis, venenatis sed tincidunt quis, auctor a orci. Aliquam mauris leo, lacinia eu placerat vitae, placerat 
                sit amet sapien. Etiam eget dolor at neque dapibus pretium auctor non dui. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum rhoncus 
                urna id enim volutpat vehicula. Proin ut massa diam, quis condimentum sem. Nullam ac scelerisque neque. Donec tristique 
                tristique elit, nec vulputate turpis suscipit quis. Nam nisl purus, blandit non hendrerit eu, vestibulum vel justo. 
                Curabitur et massa sapien.Praesent laoreet, risus eu facilisis sodales, urna lectus condimentum felis, laoreet ullamcorper 
                sapien urna in lorem. Nulla ut sem sapien, ut aliquet augue. Curabitur nec lorem risus, in interdum augue. Sed aliquam sapien
                in sapien viverra iaculis mattis eros pulvinar. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse viverra purus vitae nibh lacinia
                at blandit arcu auctor. Mauris sapien lacus, euismod eget malesuada condimentum, bibendum a quam. Phasellus faucibus, orci in
                ultricies mollis, orci tortor sagittis eros, non iaculis lorem orci nec quam. Donec luctus bibendum risus et gravida. Sed at
                tortor vel metus elementum euismod. 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Now]

[image: desiredResult]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/ZS4RT/7/

Things may be different if you want to have more floating elements, though.

Answer (score 1):

It move to the right because of **float:right** property in CSS. Add **clear** property to CSS so it cannot wrap around container above it.